# What special characters I should escape in T-SQL strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What special characters I should escape in T-SQL (SQL Server) string?

```
SET @email = ''alex_USA$info@example.com''
```

Fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want @email to have the value `'alex_USA$info@example.com'`, try:

```
SET @email = '''alex_USA$info@example.com'''
```

Comment: Could you please give a link to the documentation page where it is explained?

Comment: @yegor256 This page has some info on escaping strings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx. See example B.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be two single quotes in that query...

```
set @email = 'alex_USA$info@example.com'
```

will work just fine...

You'll need to escape single quotes, which is done by putting 2 single quotes.  If for example you really wanted `'alex_USA$info@example.com'` with the quotes in the database, you would replace `'` with `''` in the data, and still quote it:

```
set @email = '''alex_USA$info@example.com'''
```

Comment: Could you please give a link to the documentation page where it is explained?

Comment: He's using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: It is SQL Server :) (see my question)

Answer (score 0):

No need for the second set of single quotes.

```
SET @email = 'alex_USA$info@example.com'
```

Comment: Could you please give a link to the documentation page where it is explained?